# Gradually speeding up a video in Vegas Pro

Tags: video-editor, time-lapse

In Vegas Pro 17, how could you make a video speed up gradually — like 100% increasing to 110%, increasing to 120%, increasing to 140%...so it goes faster and faster smoothly?

Comment: This question has multiple answers, telling us what editor you're using would be a big help.

Comment: Im using Vegas Pro 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be pretty simple if your video editor support this.

For example here's how you do it in Adobe's Premiere Pro: